# Windows 7 & VB Classic Code: Any runtime issues?

Tags: windows, winapi, com, vb6, activex

Microsoft has promised that VB6 code will continue to work on Windows 7, but has anyone noticed any gotchas specific to running VB6 code in the Windows 7 RC?

And for that matter, any issues with COM objects and ActiveX controls outside of VB6?  I remember Microsoft saying that they'll ensure THEIR controls continue to work and end it at that; so I'm wondering what sort of under-the-hood change this entails...

We have a oodles of legacy controls which we need to migrate out--VB6 and C++--but it takes time to make it happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed one, but it's minor and probably not what you are looking for.

If you change the DPI to something other than 96, the checkbox control looks really odd, like someone cut it and it's showing you its guts.  The same applies to the checkbox on the ListBox/ListView.

Comment: Well, it *is* something.  Though it's hard to tell if it's truly the VB runtime misbehaving, or some weird issue with the display adapter/driver.

Comment: I've tried it on various PCs - all the same result.  I believe Vista had the same issue.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I don't suppose it would be possible to see a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered anything in terms of VB6 issues that is new since Vista.

Of course if your programs try to parasitize users' email profiles via MAPI, CDO, or something be aware that Win7 has no Outlook Express *or* Windows Mail at all.

DPI issues exist in Both Vista and Win7, and the cure is the same: you need to declare DPI awareness via an application manifest (and of course code for varying DPI when sizing and placing controls, fonts, etc.).

Comment: Anything is possible, but Microsoft seems to be driving people toward Live Mail.  I really would not expect an OE/WM user to pick something as random as Thunderbird out of the air.  More likely they'd just use some Web email service if they don't buy into Live Mail.  I didn't expect Live Mail to support Simple MAPI, but from a few attempts to extract intelligence from Google (what a wasteland these days!) I get the idea it may.